# What's happening with PHP's intval() and strval()?

Tags: php

So I got this:

```
$n = "19.99";

echo (int) ($n * 100);
echo (int) strval($n * 100);
```

That outputs:

```
1998
1999
```

And I just don't get it. What happened? `$n * 100` is 1999 (float), why aren't they the same then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floats don't have arbitrary precision. The result of `19.99 * 100` is actually represented as `1998.9999999999`.

If you print that, it'll show as `1999`. That's what strval() does. Whereas (int) will floor it down.

Answer (score 2):

Also check...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

You will see how everything works.

```
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 10
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 9
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 10
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 9
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 8
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 8
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9
```

Answer (score 0):

To multiply two arbitrary precision numbers use `bcmul` function.

```
echo (int)(bcmul('19.99', '100')); // 1999
echo (int)(19.99 * 100); // 1998
```

Note that the two operands of `bcmul` function are strings because according to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php) :

> Passing values of type float to a BCMath function which expects a string as operand may not have the desired effect due to the way PHP converts float values to string, namely that the string may be in exponential notation (what is not supported by BCMath), and that the decimal separator is locale dependend (while BCMath always expects a decimal point).